# How is html input field size deciphered when using EditorTemplate in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using [Brad Wilsons](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) Custom Editor templates in my project. However the size of my input fields on a page do not seem to correspond with the column size in the database. ex. My textbox shows with a size 5 when in fact my database field is varchar(50). how does MVC/.NET translate/resolve what the size of the fields should be?

Comment: FYI : It is brad wilson.  I am leaving it to you to correct it yourself.

Comment: @asawyer: Should be "He is XXXX, not XyXXX"  :)

Comment: @Shyju I think we are missing the point here arent we?

Comment: I would assume its css, but I didn't see any on that page, so I can't be sure.

Comment: Do you mean the textbox width is 5 chars wide?  Or that it stops accepting input at 5 chars? (maxlength?)

Comment: textbox width is 5 chars wide